# UnderscoreJS: trim array of objects based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, underscore.js

I have an array of `JSON` object as shown below:

```
var data = [
  {name: '', age: 12},
  {name: 'bcd', age: 15},
  {name: 'cdf', age: 13},
  {name: '', age: 11},
  {name: 'fgh', age: 8},
  {name: '', age: 10},
];
```

using `underscore` I want to trim this object in such a way that it should return:

```
[{name: 'bcd', age: 15},
{name: 'cdf', age: 13},
{name: '', age: 11},
{name: 'fgh', age: 8}]
```

I tried with below code:

```
var firstIndex = _.indexOf(data, _.find(data, function(d){ return d.name !== ''; }));

var lastIndex = _.indexOf(data, _.find(data.slice().reverse(), function(d){ return d.name !== ''; }));

console.log(data.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex + 1) );
```

But I think, there should be a better way than this.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghxrLnfg/28/)

**Edit:**

I want all data from the top and bottom to be trimmed where name is blank. But not in middle of the array element.

Same as `string.Trim()` method. when I apply trim on " one two three " text, it will remove blank space from the starting and end but not the space between words.

Comment: What is the logic of the returned object

Comment: You want the blank name with age 11?

Comment: You want to remove first and last item from the array?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I have updated question and mentioned what it should return.

Comment: @brk I have updated question and mentioned what it should return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic is fine, just use [`_.findLastIndex()`](http://underscorejs.org/#findLastIndex) instead of using `_.findIndex()` on the reversed array:

```js
const data = [
  {name: '', age: 7},
  {name: '', age: 12},
  {name: 'bcd', age: 15},
  {name: 'cdf', age: 13},
  {name: '', age: 11},
  {name: 'fgh', age: 8},
  {name: '', age: 10},
  {name: '', age: 12},
  {name: '', age: 14},
];

function trimArray(predicate, arr) {
  const start = _.findIndex(arr, predicate);
  const end = _.findLastIndex(arr, predicate);
  
  return arr.slice(start, end + 1);
}

const result = trimArray((o) => o.name !== '', data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I knew that there must be better solution than I have applied :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to return the array without first and last item, then use `slice`

```
var trimmedData = data.slice( 1, data.length - 1 );
```

> I want all data from the top and bottom to be trimmed where name is
>   blank. But not in middle of the array element.

Define a `trimLeftFn`

```
var trimLeftFn = arr => {
   var hasValue = false;
   arr = arr.filter( s => {
      hasValue = hasValue || s.name.length > 0;
      return hasValue;
   });
   return arr;
};

var trimmedData = trimLeftFn( trimLeftFn (data ).reverse() ).reverse();
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [
  {name: '', age: 12},
  {name: 'bcd', age: 15},
  {name: 'cdf', age: 13},
  {name: '', age: 11},
  {name: 'fgh', age: 8},
  {name: '', age: 10},
];

var trimLeftFn = arr => {
  var hasValue = false;
  arr = arr.filter(s => {
    hasValue = hasValue || s.name.length > 0;
    return hasValue;
  });
  return arr;
};

var trimmedData = trimLeftFn(trimLeftFn(data).reverse()).reverse();

console.log(trimmedData);
```